# Databricks photon vs catalyst Optimizer

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I was reading about the new databricks feature of delta engine which is powered by photon. From the understanding i have by reading i have a feeling that its similar to catalyst optimizer. Will the photon replace the catalyst.

How is the photon engine different to catalyst optimizer

The link is referred below

https://databricks.com/blog/2020/06/24/introducing-delta-engine.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are conflating two things:

- Catalyst optimizer is about coming up "Steps to take to execute the query". For example, the optimizer will decide how and when to do the join, aggregations, filters etc. When it should do what. This is also called "Physical Plan" in technical parlance. (Catalyst optimizer is more for logical planning but that is a finer detail)
- The execution engine is actually the engine that carries out the steps decided by the optimizer. It does not second guess the steps, but rather makes sure to carry them out as efficiently as possible.

Delta Engine (or Photon) is an execution engine and not an optimizer. It is more directly comparable with the Tungsten (whole stage code generation) execution engine currently available in open source Spark. Both Tungsten and Delta-Engine are execution engines.

Comment: It seems that Databricks has completely rewritten the engine from Java (Spark using Scala) to C++. If the Photon is really fast (4x or 10x or whatever their claims are) how is it gonna impact open-source Apache Spark?

Comment: @Goutham Anush, it wont necessarily affect anything, as Databricks uses Photon as a premium service when you need just a bit more speed. Usually with spark, its fast enough anyways. I highly doubt claims that its even 4x faster than Tungsten

Answer (score 0):

The catalyst optimizer applies only to Spark Sql. Catalyst is working with your code you write for spark sql, for example DataFrame operations, filtering ect. Photon is delta storage query engine and applies to new analytical feature in Databricks. It is linked to delta storage engine.
Essentially they are slightly different tools each specializing in optimizing different queries. They are both spark compatible but photon is linked to delta so it would make sense to keep them separate since not everyone is using delta.

Answer (score 0):

On the financial side, Catalyst is "free" as it's just part of the runtime.

Photon requires a 2x increase in DBU costs, however your cloud costs are the same.  So if your job is not sped up enough with Photon, then you you will likely be overpaying.

[We wrote an article that went deep into this topic and ran some tests with the TPC-DI 1TB benchmark.](https://synccomputing.com/databricks-photon-and-graviton-instances-worth-it/)